# Error: Access through untrusted domain

Tags: raspbian, nextcloud

NexctcloudPi (Raspbian\Debian) was installed on a rpi3 on a USB-SSD.

Initial tests were successful.  Access via:

- duckdns
- lets encrypt certificate

was successful after initial setup.

The system was rebooted and now returns:

[image]

What Debian commands can be used to probe and test to identify the root cause of the problem?

A simple (ELI5) explanation of the error is appreciated: thank you

Comment: Have you read the linked documentation? Did you compare the 2 files named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated at https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#trusted-domains

The `trusted_domain` configuration directive in the `config.php` file tells `nextcloud` what domains (host names) this nextcloud instance is known as.

If you access it as `https://somehostname.example.com` and `somehostname.example.com` is not among the `trusted_domain` list, you'll get that error message. So you need to edit that configuration file, to add that domain name.